How to use ros_gz_interfaces to bridge ign services into ros2 Humble? Only WorldControl service is working and the rest are not
I was able to use ros_gz_interfaces WorldControl service only by bridging ign services with ros2 services.
ign gazebo sahpes.sdf
ros2 run ros_gz_bridge parameter_bridge /world/shapes/control@ros_gz_interfaces/srv/ControlWorld
ros2 service call /world/shapes/control ros_gz_interfaces/srv/ControlWorld "{world_control: {pause: false}}"

But when using SetEntityPose service. The bridging always fails.
ros2 run ros_gz_bridge parameter_bridge /world/shapes/set_pose@ros_gz_interfaces/srv/SetEntityPose

Always getting this feedback
ros_gz_interfaces/srv/SetEntityPose}, gz request type {}, gz request type {}, gz reply type name {}

And there is no ros2 service in service list called /world/shapes/set_pose. There is no proper guide in their documentation too about using the Entity services too. Just like SetEntityPose service other services respond exactly the same except WorldControl.
